# XKB: enable a LED for specific layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, ibus

There's a widely used XKB option `grp_led:scroll` to light ScrollLock LED for cycling between layouts. Unfortunately, [it doesn't work with ibus ATM](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1785) because the implementation makes XKB consider every layout as a primary. [There's a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1245188) indicating it worked at some point, but not now.

As a workaround, I want the LED to rather light on for specific layout.

So far I found the implementation of LED light for cycle of layouts *(`/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/ledscroll`)*:

```
partial xkb_compatibility "group_lock" {
    indicator "Scroll Lock" {
        modifiers= None;
        groups=All-group1;
    };
};
```

I'd probably need to swap `groups=All-group1;` with something like `layout=ru;` to enable LED for `ru` layout, but I couldn't figure out the actual variable *(i.e. `layout` is probably not what it's called)*. Nor I can find the layout name implementation, because `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ru` *(and whole `/usr/share/X11/xkb` except for a few irrelevant files, for that matter)* surprisingly doesn't have `"ru"` anywhere.